# s-nail: /home/ion/Maildir: No such entry, file or directory

Tags: 18.04, postfix

I am trying to setup postfix on my server with the tutorial [How To Install and Configure Postfix on Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-on-ubuntu-18-04).

But after running `echo 'init' | s-nail -s 'init' -Snorecord ion`, and `s-nail` I am getting this:

```
s-nail: /home/ion/Maildir: No such entry, file or directory
s-nail version v14.9.6.  Type `?' for help
(Currently no active mailbox)
No more mail.
There are new messages in the error message ring (denoted by ERROR)
  The `errors' command manages this message ring
ERROR# ? Interrupt
```

The following is my `main.cf`:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mail.dots.md
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = mail.dots.md, dots.md, mail.dots.md, localhost.dots.md, localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command = 
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
home_mailbox = Maildir/
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround:

```
sudo ln -s ~/Maildir/ /var/mail/username
```